# Copy Photos From Phone to Computer and Store By Date

Tags: lumia, transfer, photos

When I was using a digital camera, I used to copy my photos from the camera to my computer. I would store them in my Photos directory, and the transfer process would automatically create a folder for every different date that pictures were taken and then place the photos by date in the folders.

I like that setup.

Now I've got a Windows phone (Nokia Lumia 710). Is there any way to copy my pics from the phone to the computer and do it the same way, having it automatically create folders for each date and place the pics for that date in each folder?

I don't believe this can be done with Zune.

Is there any way of doing this automatically?

Comment: Why not just look at your Pictures library grouped by date, and sync to that library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was pleasantly surprised to discover that if I connect my phone via USB to my computer, then one of the options that comes up is to "Import pictures and videos using Windows Live Photo Gallery" which I have installed on my computer.

This gives you various options for the Folder name, including:

- Date Imported + Name
- Date Taken + Name
- Date Taken Range + Name
- Name + DateTaken
- Name + DateTakenRange
- Name
- (None)

and the following options for the file name:

- Name
- Original File Name
- Original File Name (Preserve Folders)
- Name + Date Taken
- Date Taken + Name

This is exactly what I wanted. I have chosen "Date Taken + Name" as the folder name and "Original File Name" as the picture name.

It also has useful options to Delete files from device after importing, and to rotate photos during import.

Answer (score 3):

Zune doesn't do this, but there are a lot of utilities that do. [Here is one I found called Picture Sorter](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/organize-camera-pictures-videos-into-make-model-date-folders-picturesorter/). This should work with any images, not just those taken with your phone.